# How to select only the rows from A matching given ID's from B - Table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this example table below. I'm using a inner join between table A and table B and would like to only select rows from table A where they match all Table B given id's. For instance I would like to only show rows from table A where table B Id's are 27 and 65 **and** table A **must** have a relation to rows with both id 27 and 65 in table B to show up in the result.

**Question:** How can I create such a query given this example?

```
A          B
-----      -----
id         id
name       a_id
           value
```

Hopefully you can understand my example above, any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking here. Why isn't a `JOIN` working here? If "`A`" has a relationship to 2 rows in "`B`" then an `INNER JOIN` is going to return both those rows.

Comment: The inner join alone won't solve the problem: as the OP said, he'd like to receive only rows where both IDs 27 and 65 are referenced. So I guess a ROW_NUMBER or some other Windowfunction should do the trick. Basically it should be something like `SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, OW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.a_id ORDER by b.id) rn FROM TabA a JOIN TabB b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE b.id IN (27, 65)...` - and this used as subquery could be filtered by `WHERE rn = 2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my comment as answer - seemingly, it works with multiple matches as well as with mixed results (matches + additional rows):

```
CREATE TABLE TabA(
  ID int
  ,Name nvarchar(100)
 )
 
 CREATE TABLE TabB(
  ID int
  ,a_ID int
  ,Val decimal(19,4)
 )

 INSERT INTO TabA VALUES
(1, N'Test1 - two matches')
,(2, N'Test2 - one match')
,(3, N'Test3 - two matches + 1')
,(4, N'Test4 - two matches not unique')
,(5, N'Test5 - no matches')

INSERT INTO TabB VALUES
(27, 1, 0.5)
,(65, 1, 0.75)
,(27, 2, 1)
,(27, 3, 1.5)
,(65, 3, 2.5)
,(68, 3, 2.5)
,(27, 4, 1.5)
,(65, 4, 2.5)
,(27, 4, 3.5)
,(65, 4, 4.5)
,(1, 6, 0)
GO

WITH cte AS(
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id AS b_id, SUM(b.val) AS val
  FROM TabA a
  JOIN TabB b ON b.a_id = a.id AND b.ID IN (27, 65)
  GROUP BY a.id, a.name, b.id
)
SELECT x.ID, x.Name
FROM(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY b_id) rn
    FROM cte c
) x
WHERE rn = 2
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa6ec5/13/1

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark, if what Tyron78 suggest is correct. Seems like, perhaps, a `HAVING` and some conditional aggregation will work:

```sql
SELECT A.id,
       A.[name]
FROM A
     JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
GROUP BY A.id,
         A.[name]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN B.id WHEN 27 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN B.id WHEN 65 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

This assumes that `a.id` is unique (it is an ID after all), but then this assumes that `b.id` *isn't* Unique; because if `B.Id` *is* unique then this would (again) just need a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT A.id,
       A.[name]
FROM A
     JOIN B27 ON A.id = B27.a_id
     JOIN B65 ON A.id = B65.a_id
WHERE B27.Id = 27
  AND B65.ID = 65;
```

The former, however, will likely perform (slightly) better anyway still though, as it only requires one lookup in table `B`, not 2.